# On the existence of a complicated fractal-like set of finite perimeter

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f\in BV(\Bbb R^n)$ be an integer-valued function that maps into $\{0, 1\}$ and is identically $0$ outside some bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$. In particular, $f$ determines a bounded Caccioppoli set $E = f^{-1}(\{1\})$. We will assume that $|E| > 0$.

By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, we know that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{|\{ y \in B_r(x) : y \notin E \}|}{|B_r|} = 0
$$
for almost every $x$ in $E$. However, it is entirely possible that at such a point $x$, we may still have
$$
|A_r(x)| := |\{ y \in B_r(x) : y \notin E \}|>0
$$
for every $r>0$ (e.g. consider a point $x$ at the tip of an internal cusp). Let us denote the set of all such `bad points' by
$$
\mathcal A := \{ x \in E : |A_r(x)|>0 \text{ for every } r >0  \}.
$$

**Question:** Is it possible for $\mathcal A$ to have positive measure, or even full measure in $E$? I imagine that for such a set $E$ with $|\mathcal A|>0$ to exist, it must have a really complicated fractal-like structure. I am hoping that $f$ being of bounded variation would prevent that from happening, but I am not aware of a result in the literature regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. In what follows I will refer to the book [EG].

By Example on p.198 we know wthat if $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open with smooth boundary and $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial U)<\infty$, then $f=\chi_\bar{U}\in BV(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial U)<M$, then the $BV$ norm of $f$ is bounded by a constant depending on $M$ only.

Let now $U_k$ be $B^n(0,1)$ with $k$ smaller and pairwise disjoint closed balls removed from the interior of $B^n(0,1)$.
We construct $U_{k+1}$ from $U_k$ by removing one ball from $U_k$.
If the balls that we remove are small enough, we can guarantee that $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial {U}_k)<M$, where $M$ is independent of $k$.
Let
$$
K=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bar{U}_k.
$$
We can guarantee that the interior of the compact set $K$ is empty by choosing the balls that we remove wisely. We can also guarantee that the measure of $K$ is as close to the measure of $B^n(0,1)$ as we want (by making sure that the balls that we remove are small enough).

The $BV$ norms of the functions $f_k=\chi_{\bar{U}_k}$ are uniformly bounded. Clearly, $f_k\to \chi_K$ in $L^1$. Since the $BV$ norms of the functions $f_k$ are uniformly bounded, Theorem 5.2 from p.199 implies that $f=\chi_K\in BV(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Since the set $K$ has no interior, every point in $K$ is a `bad point' according to you definition of bad points.

[EG] L. Evans, R.L. Gariepy, [**Measure theory and fine properties of functions**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450314), Textbooks in Mathematics. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4822-4238-6/hbk). 309 p. (2015). [ZBL1310.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1310.28001).

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I was thinking about a similar counterexample, but I failed to consider that we can pick the size of the balls to shrink at a sufficiently rapid rate so that what is left has positive measure (I arrived at a set $E$ that is almost a porous set and has zero measure).